# How to get all the element count under the div with selenium

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I am trying to get the count of the search results returned in MakeMyTrip application by searching the flights from Hyderabad to Bangalore. By using the below I am able to get the text but how to verify how many number of search results returned.

String output = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"left-side--wrapper\"]/div[3]")).getText();[MakeMyTrip Flight Search](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0urtv.png)

```
System.out.println(output);
```

Thanks in Advance

Comment: you will have to write a generic XPath which will capture all the search results and then invoke driver.findElements(<your xpath goes here>). This will return a list of webelement whose size will be the number of search results returned

Answer (score 0):

You should use `driver.findElements();` method like this below:

```
// your webelement
By eachSearchElement = By.xpath("//*[@id='left-side--wrapper']/div[3]");

// getting all of available elements on the page and store them in List
List <WebElement> allSearchElements = driver.findElements(eachSearchElement);

// then just simply get the size of particular List above
int howManyElements = allSearchElements.size();

System.out.println("There are " + howManyElements + " present on the page");
```

Hope this will help.